# Is there any way I can draw a wedge and dashed chemistry bond inline, in Latex?

Tags: inline, chemistry, mhchem

[image: figure of the bonds]

I'm trying to draw bonds inline in a section that discusses chemistry notation. 
I wanted to have them in line, as opposed to referencing a figure.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper, margin = 1in}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\graphicspath{  {Images/}{../Images/}   }

\usepackage{amsthm, amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb, gensymb}
\usepackage{titling, titlesec, setspace, mhchem}
\usepackage{pdfpages, subfiles}
\begin{document}
 A wedge bond (<have fgure here>) is...
\end{document}
```

Comment: What about `\includegraphics`? You can add it inline. Even better: You could try to draw such graphics with LaTeX packages.

Comment: Could you provide an example? I don't know how to use \includegraphics for inline images.

Comment: Just for clarification: Do you want a single bond to be displayed or the figure given following that link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `chemfig` package offers a command for drawing cram bonds, which you can use inline.

The `\setcrambond*{<dim1>}{<dim2>}{<dim3>}` takes 3 inputs. `<dim1>` controls the base width of the wedge (default is 1.5pt, affects both types of wedges). `<dim2>` controls the thickness of the lines in the dashed wedge (default is 1pt). `<dim3>` controls the spacing between the lines in the dashed wedge (default is 2pt). Adjust these as you see fit.

I also used `\setatomsep{<dim>}` to set the length of the bond.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setcrambond*{1ex}{1pt}{1.5pt}
\setatomsep{2em}

\begin{document}
    This is an in line wedge (\chemfig[yshift=0.7ex]{>}) and dashed wedge (\chemfig[yshift=0.7ex]{>:})
\end{document}
```

[image: wedge]

---

**The Molecule**

Just thought you might want to draw the molecule as well. You can change the scale however you want. (Left it in since you might want to place the molecule in-line, for strange reasons.)

```
\chemfig[][scale=1]{-[1]([:130]<)([:60]<:)-[-1]-[1]OH}
```

[image: example molecule]

---

**Additional information:**

- If you would like the bonds to point the other direction, use `<` and
  `<:` instead.
- For more info, you can check out the [`chemfig`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf) documentation.

Comment: Have you had a look at the image (link in OP)? There are some more things in the bond.

Comment: @TeXnician OP only wants to draw the bond in-line, not the whole molecule, no? I'll add in the dashed wedge bond in in an edit

Comment: Maybe you're right, for me it's actually not fully clear.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version with inline `\includegraphics` (adjust height to your need), if you really want to include an image instead of drawing it with LaTeX:

[image: bond]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
 A wedge bond \includegraphics[height=.5\baselineskip]{example-image} is...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works! How would you draw it in Latex, just for curiosity?

Comment: @user3603077 There are packages for chemical figures (e.g. `chemfig`). But I only know that those are capable of bond-drawings. I haven't used them for years. Probably you could wait for somebody else to answer this directly or ask a new question.